# Как сделать закрашивание SVG иконки на hover?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, png

Есть две иконки: 1-ая (иконка сверху) стоит обычная, но при ховере она должна закрашиваться (иконка снизу). Как такое реализовать, да еще и плавно, желательно?

P.S. Вариант только создать две png иконки и подменять при ховер ?

[image: Две иконки]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="802.38" height="648.026" viewBox="0 0 752.23086 607.52399"><path d="M207.718 580.578C126.42 549.449 64.078 479.287 20.494 369.87c-36.622-91.94-24.36-170.383 38.377-245.493C229.963-80.46 607.95-20.792 659.402 219.174c15.533 72.446-14.758 141.938-87.96 201.792-56.941 46.558-67.889 49.67-167.664 47.662-159.68-3.213-174.019-5.051-156.258-20.03 9.75-8.223 40.053-7.188 78.133 2.668 159.754 41.35 307.357-52.363 307.357-195.14 0-84.984-32.612-142.132-109.233-191.42-110.36-70.99-278.756-63.274-393.314 18.021C.695 174.817-31.78 387.982 90.28 346.49c61.246-20.819 86.754-14.582 117.006 28.608 29.44 42.032 31.74 79.593 6.927 113.112-20.644 27.886 56.107 53.876 160.43 54.326 162.567.7 253.162-66.809 301.046-224.333 23.072-75.9 66.192-88.557 75.151-22.058 14.243 105.72-82.525 235.797-212.444 285.573-90.954 34.847-238.015 34.34-330.677-1.14zm315.109-14.018c86.577-33.16 138.765-77.586 180.795-153.907 33.686-61.17 43.405-138.042 17.453-138.042-8.422 0-20.713 24.521-27.314 54.49-20.941 95.074-76.682 160.325-170.715 199.844-94.718 39.806-164.137 45.14-253.593 19.483-67.633-19.398-187.79-94.55-187.79-117.452 0-8.559 15.88-3.443 35.287 11.37 30.903 23.585 104.612 47.121 78.434 25.044-5.524-4.66-1.84-16.809 8.189-26.999 24.466-24.862-30.793-97.843-65.563-86.59-13.588 4.397-33.763 7.995-44.833 7.995-34.764 0-21.912 82.713 20.34 130.912 82.433 94.03 268.818 127.66 409.31 73.852zM311.312 413.267c-106.2-38.96-127.309-154.547-41.448-226.957 89.585-75.553 208.08-38.693 208.08 64.726 0 54.25-21.448 75.56-86.148 85.592l-43.074 6.68 46.15 1.978c86.03 3.689 139.417-79.57 97.543-152.124-30.498-52.842-115.843-93.666-157.717-75.442-20.837 9.068-39.499 7.83-55.996-3.717-20.101-14.07-24.743-11.867-24.743 11.743 0 38.143-43.369 67.463-81.62 55.18-24.353-7.819-26.104-6.125-8.835 8.546 11.846 10.064 21.537 40.038 21.537 66.61 0 38.992-8.88 51.158-46.045 63.074-90.87 29.137-115.472-12.21-66.308-111.445 16.446-33.195 32.76-47.644 46.002-40.742 13.87 7.23 17.032 3.033 9.76-12.95-14.554-31.986 69.654-89.312 99.996-68.075 15.518 10.861 23.778 6.935 30.41-14.456 9.453-30.484 86.956-42.319 106.096-16.201 5.307 7.242 25.134 9.751 44.06 5.577 18.926-4.174 54.179 3.334 78.338 16.685 147.187 81.333 146.352 284.19-1.383 336.249-71.931 25.347-104.385 25.248-174.655-.53zm187.99-24.85c51.387-22.205 86.772-97.918 76.36-163.386-6.93-43.578-25.71-71.953-70.558-106.616-60.043-46.406-113.308-61.633-113.308-32.391 0 8.163 19.965 22.514 44.366 31.89 89.71 34.472 119.261 139.657 57.76 205.595-68.057 72.968-205.503 40.76-205.503-48.156 0-49.149 35.581-77.325 89.506-70.878 28.958 3.462 39.715 14.26 39.715 39.864 0 19.314-9.691 37.84-21.537 41.17-12.635 3.552-21.537-6.458-21.537-24.217 0-34.297-26.018-40.722-40.047-9.889-13.391 29.431 28.311 70.855 65.184 64.748 44.829-7.425 67.945-45.323 54.73-89.729-33.614-112.95-217.703-58.528-217.703 64.359 0 98.901 139.551 150.792 262.572 97.635zM328.823 310.31c-5.611-12.332-13.898-19.306-18.414-15.497-4.516 3.809-3.1 13.9 3.145 22.423 16.99 23.183 26.92 18.68 15.27-6.926zm-184.972-12.076c1.035-1.006 6.776-19.061 12.756-40.124 7.297-25.705 2.189-44.374-15.536-56.78-34.408-24.084-53.645-6.236-68.952 63.97-11.791 54.083-10.767 55.698 28.811 45.419 22.57-5.862 41.885-11.48 42.92-12.485zm74.9-146.374c13.15-13.362 15.109-29.462 5.369-44.14-13.638-20.552-18.734-19.935-46.123 5.589-16.935 15.782-25.697 35.645-19.471 44.14 15.55 21.22 35.683 19.35 60.226-5.589zm121.356-74.969c0-11.132-10.338-20.24-22.973-20.24-32.026 0-45.144 13.914-34.717 36.829 11.05 24.286 57.69 10.875 57.69-16.589zm333.636 88.836c-5.967-13.115-2.588-30.814 7.51-39.33 26.25-22.139 75.989-1.904 69.131 28.124-7.637 33.448-62.847 41.52-76.64 11.206zm62.644-4.94c0-18.92-20.482-31.503-37.143-22.82-17.82 9.289-2.455 34.929 20.93 34.929 8.917 0 16.213-5.45 16.213-12.11z" fill="#a1a1a1"/></svg>
```

Comment: Поставить две друг над другом, менять прозрачность у верхней.

Comment: Так и хотел, интересно узнать есть ли еще варианты :)

Comment: А при чем тут метка svg, если вы собираетесь на png сделать?

Comment: Если иконка все же на svg, прикрепите ее к вопросу

Comment: svg как вариант возможный, я говорю, вдруг есть варианты с svg реализацией.

Comment: @YourDeveloper есть. Поэтому и говорю прикрепить к вопросу

Comment: Добавил svg, маленький вопрос - при переводе из png в svg углы скругляются так и должно быть ? Их надо в ручную править уже на свг?

Comment: Подскажите по svg "при переводе из png в svg углы скругляются так и должно быть ? Их надо в ручную править уже на свг?"

Comment: @YourDeveloper никогда не конвертировал png в svg, поэтому ответить не могу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы при ховере изменять цвет заливки, используйте свойство `fill-opacity` и, при необходимости, `stroke-opacity`:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 162px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

path {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  fill: #f00;
  stroke: #f00;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

svg:hover path {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="802.38" height="648.026" viewBox="0 0 752.23086 607.52399"><path d="M207.718 580.578C126.42 549.449 64.078 479.287 20.494 369.87c-36.622-91.94-24.36-170.383 38.377-245.493C229.963-80.46 607.95-20.792 659.402 219.174c15.533 72.446-14.758 141.938-87.96 201.792-56.941 46.558-67.889 49.67-167.664 47.662-159.68-3.213-174.019-5.051-156.258-20.03 9.75-8.223 40.053-7.188 78.133 2.668 159.754 41.35 307.357-52.363 307.357-195.14 0-84.984-32.612-142.132-109.233-191.42-110.36-70.99-278.756-63.274-393.314 18.021C.695 174.817-31.78 387.982 90.28 346.49c61.246-20.819 86.754-14.582 117.006 28.608 29.44 42.032 31.74 79.593 6.927 113.112-20.644 27.886 56.107 53.876 160.43 54.326 162.567.7 253.162-66.809 301.046-224.333 23.072-75.9 66.192-88.557 75.151-22.058 14.243 105.72-82.525 235.797-212.444 285.573-90.954 34.847-238.015 34.34-330.677-1.14zm315.109-14.018c86.577-33.16 138.765-77.586 180.795-153.907 33.686-61.17 43.405-138.042 17.453-138.042-8.422 0-20.713 24.521-27.314 54.49-20.941 95.074-76.682 160.325-170.715 199.844-94.718 39.806-164.137 45.14-253.593 19.483-67.633-19.398-187.79-94.55-187.79-117.452 0-8.559 15.88-3.443 35.287 11.37 30.903 23.585 104.612 47.121 78.434 25.044-5.524-4.66-1.84-16.809 8.189-26.999 24.466-24.862-30.793-97.843-65.563-86.59-13.588 4.397-33.763 7.995-44.833 7.995-34.764 0-21.912 82.713 20.34 130.912 82.433 94.03 268.818 127.66 409.31 73.852zM311.312 413.267c-106.2-38.96-127.309-154.547-41.448-226.957 89.585-75.553 208.08-38.693 208.08 64.726 0 54.25-21.448 75.56-86.148 85.592l-43.074 6.68 46.15 1.978c86.03 3.689 139.417-79.57 97.543-152.124-30.498-52.842-115.843-93.666-157.717-75.442-20.837 9.068-39.499 7.83-55.996-3.717-20.101-14.07-24.743-11.867-24.743 11.743 0 38.143-43.369 67.463-81.62 55.18-24.353-7.819-26.104-6.125-8.835 8.546 11.846 10.064 21.537 40.038 21.537 66.61 0 38.992-8.88 51.158-46.045 63.074-90.87 29.137-115.472-12.21-66.308-111.445 16.446-33.195 32.76-47.644 46.002-40.742 13.87 7.23 17.032 3.033 9.76-12.95-14.554-31.986 69.654-89.312 99.996-68.075 15.518 10.861 23.778 6.935 30.41-14.456 9.453-30.484 86.956-42.319 106.096-16.201 5.307 7.242 25.134 9.751 44.06 5.577 18.926-4.174 54.179 3.334 78.338 16.685 147.187 81.333 146.352 284.19-1.383 336.249-71.931 25.347-104.385 25.248-174.655-.53zm187.99-24.85c51.387-22.205 86.772-97.918 76.36-163.386-6.93-43.578-25.71-71.953-70.558-106.616-60.043-46.406-113.308-61.633-113.308-32.391 0 8.163 19.965 22.514 44.366 31.89 89.71 34.472 119.261 139.657 57.76 205.595-68.057 72.968-205.503 40.76-205.503-48.156 0-49.149 35.581-77.325 89.506-70.878 28.958 3.462 39.715 14.26 39.715 39.864 0 19.314-9.691 37.84-21.537 41.17-12.635 3.552-21.537-6.458-21.537-24.217 0-34.297-26.018-40.722-40.047-9.889-13.391 29.431 28.311 70.855 65.184 64.748 44.829-7.425 67.945-45.323 54.73-89.729-33.614-112.95-217.703-58.528-217.703 64.359 0 98.901 139.551 150.792 262.572 97.635zM328.823 310.31c-5.611-12.332-13.898-19.306-18.414-15.497-4.516 3.809-3.1 13.9 3.145 22.423 16.99 23.183 26.92 18.68 15.27-6.926zm-184.972-12.076c1.035-1.006 6.776-19.061 12.756-40.124 7.297-25.705 2.189-44.374-15.536-56.78-34.408-24.084-53.645-6.236-68.952 63.97-11.791 54.083-10.767 55.698 28.811 45.419 22.57-5.862 41.885-11.48 42.92-12.485zm74.9-146.374c13.15-13.362 15.109-29.462 5.369-44.14-13.638-20.552-18.734-19.935-46.123 5.589-16.935 15.782-25.697 35.645-19.471 44.14 15.55 21.22 35.683 19.35 60.226-5.589zm121.356-74.969c0-11.132-10.338-20.24-22.973-20.24-32.026 0-45.144 13.914-34.717 36.829 11.05 24.286 57.69 10.875 57.69-16.589zm333.636 88.836c-5.967-13.115-2.588-30.814 7.51-39.33 26.25-22.139 75.989-1.904 69.131 28.124-7.637 33.448-62.847 41.52-76.64 11.206zm62.644-4.94c0-18.92-20.482-31.503-37.143-22.82-17.82 9.289-2.455 34.929 20.93 34.929 8.917 0 16.213-5.45 16.213-12.11z" fill="#a1a1a1"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ с двумя картинками друг над другом и изменением прозрачности верхней:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1BtB.jpg') no-repeat -20px -14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.item-wrapper {
  background-position: -20px -88px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```